# Number box alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a mobile app, where I am using two number box with label
which is working fine in portrait mode one after another, but in landscape mode I want both the number box to come in a single line which I am not able to do along with label.

I don't want to use table format. Is it possible to do it using CSS or JavaScript?

This Is the code what I am using.

```html
<div class="dx-field-label dx-text">AccountNumber</div>
<div data-bind="dxNumberBox: {value: '',placeholder: '00'}"></div>
<div class="dx-field-label dx-text">Ammount</div>
<div data-bind="dxNumberBox: {value: '',placeholder: '0.00'}"></div>
```

Comment: may be you can add `css/html` tag where UI guys can help you better

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `display:inline-block` like this

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  div.someclass {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use Responsive Web Design, which modifies the way the elements are layed out in the page depending on its size.

If you want to understand how it works, you can review the documentation of the most used RWD frameworks:

- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

In these frameworks, and some other frameworks, there is a grid system which organizes the page width in columns, usually 12, and let you specify the width of your elements in columns. The trick is that you can specify a different number of columns for each viewport size, for example:

- you can specify 12 columns for a small viewport, so that the elements take the whole width, and are layoud ot one below the other
- you can specify 6 columns for medium size, so that two elements (6+6=12) can be displayed side by side
- you can even specify 4 columns for a bigger size (3 elements side by side)
- or 3 columns (4 elements side by side).

So, to understand exactly what you want to do, review the grid of both frameworks. Or look for any other responsive grid system (there are some others).

All of these is base based upon [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), which consist in modifying the CSS depending on the viewport. I recommend using one of this frameworsk or  responsive grids systems, because they are fully tested and optimized.

If you use a full framework, you'll also get a perfectly tuned styling which works perfectly in most different devices, OSs and browsers.